# How I can change the variable in this for loop

Tags: caml

I've a problem with a loop for. In this program,

```
let f s = 
  for i = 0 to ((String.length s) - 1) do 
    print_char s.[i];
  done;;
```

For some reasons, I want to change the variable i (increase,dicrease) but this variable is not mutable and I don't see how I can change the pointer on the string s. I think to an another function which but I don't know if is the good idea ..

Comment: From what I remember of Ocaml(a caml varient), it wasn't designed to do very much assignment(such as increasing and decreasing).  It's a functional language, not an iterative one

Comment: Yes I know that but it isn't a way to change the i pointer on the string s ?

Comment: yeah it's FP.. why do you want to change the "variable"? you're probably approaching the problem from a wrong direction.

Comment: I don't want to move characters by characters. I want to jump  in the string at the i+2 or i+3 position